# disable live wallpaper

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

My question is simple. Is there a way to disable or remove the Live Wallpaper that is bundled in my application until I am ready for the user to be able to choose it?

The user needs to configure settings first in the main app, and then the Live Wallpaper can be used, but until then, I'd like for it not to appear in the list of Live Wallpapers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to disable or remove the Live Wallpaper that is bundled in my application until I am ready for the user to be able to choose it?

AFAIK, no.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at something like [this](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/removing-app-icon-launcher).  I'm not sure if it would work for live wallpapers (which are services) but it'd be worth a try.

Comment: Great resource! Thank you. Unfortunately it would have to be something in the manifest since I don't want to have to launch the app in order to run the code. The problem is users launching the live wallpaper for the first time without applying any settings.

Comment: How about adding `android:enabled="false"` to your service tag (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html).  That might start you out in the right state, then use the dynamic enabling code from above in your app.

Comment: Although, to be honest, I'd just leave the wallpaper installed as is, with some decent default settings, maybe send them to your app from the Settings button.  This way if they go looking for the livewallpaper feature first, they won't be discouraged.  Also, if they forgot they installed your app, having it in other places might remind them ;)

Comment: Wow this works brilliantly! The problem is I need them to download something and authorize first before they're allowed to "set" the wallpaper, but I am still considering having something telling them to do this from the wallpaper instead of disabling it. I just want to have both options on the table, I just tested it and it works like a charm. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to remove all the wallpaper and take default one it useful,

```
            WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager
            = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
            try {
                myWallpaperManager.clear();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

you can also set wallpaper image by same way,

```
            try {
                myWallpaperManager.setResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```